# How to append to list in python module written in rust?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I am writing a python model for heavy calculations in rust using the pyo3 bindings. However, for a rust struct with a variable containing an empty list I cannot append to that variable in python.

Does anybody know how to do this? See below for a MWE ( that I cannot get to work ):

I have a rust file called lib.rs:

```rust
// lib.rs

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use std::vec::Vec;

#[pyclass(subclass)]
pub struct TestClass {
    #[pyo3(get)]
    pub id: i32,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    pub test_list: Vec<f32>
}

#[pymethods]
impl TestClass {
    #[new]
    pub fn new(id: i32) -> TestClass {
        TestClass{
            id,
            test_list: Vec::new()
        }
    }
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn test_rust(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<TestClass>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This library is build using the `maturin` package. When I initiate the `TestClass` in python that works as expected. However, when I want to append to the class attribute `test_list` this is not happening. `test_list` still is an empty list. See for an example below:

```python
from test_rust import TestClass

foo = TestClass(1)

print(foo.test_list) # output: []
foo.test_list.append(2.3)
print(foo.test_list) # output: [] - expected: [2.3]
```

The [pyo3 documentation](https://pyo3.rs/v0.12.3/conversions/tables.html) stated that the types `Vec<T>` and `list[T]` are accepted. However, this does not work.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Having no experience with pyo3 whatsoever, but just guessing: What happens if you remove the `get` from `#[pyo3(get, set)]`, or if you remove that annotation entirely?

Comment: I think @mkrieger1 is right ... accessing `.test_list` like this **copies** it. If you do `my_list = foo.test_list`, followed by `my_list.append(2.3)` and `print(my_list)`, you will see that it actually worked, it just isn't the same list as in `foo` any more. This is due to an incompatibility with Rust's and Python's ownership models.

Comment: I would also experiment with replacing `Vec` by `PyList`.

Comment: The thing is that I need to access the `Vec`  in both rust (functions to be implemented) and python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return reference to member field in PyO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665304/return-reference-to-member-field-in-pyo3)

Comment: Also very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159723/rust-py03-how-to-get-reference-to-struct-member

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. Based on the suggested questions, I managed to write a function in rust that appends to `Vec` by using a wrapper around it, such that I can do `foo.append(2.3)`. This gives the desired result, but since I replace my python code by rust gradually, I actually need be able to do `foo.test_list.append(2.3)`. Any ideas?